# Query to return a record ONLY if it isn't already referenced in [Amount] of other records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables:

[image: db structure]

Now in my UI, I have a registrants list and a combo box field linked to `tour_att` where the user can choose a tour, which works fine.:

[image]

However, as you notice, each `tour` has a  `capacity`. Instead of showing ALL the tour `id`s, I'd like to limit the options to ONLY the id's that haven't already been selected in more than the number specified in `capacity`.

For example, if I have this record in the tours table:

```
| 1 | "10:30" | "This tour is at ten thirty" | 14 |
```

If the `id` 1 is already present in 14 `tour_att` fields in the `registrants` table records, it should not show up as an option to select, since that tour has reached its capacity.

Is there a way to make a query to do what I'm asking? This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working: (NOTE: this is msaccess SQL, so it might look a little different than regular SQL)

```
SELECT tours.id
FROM tours INNER JOIN registrants ON tours.id = registrants.tour_att
WHERE count(iif(registrants.tour_att=tours.id,1,0)) < tours.capacity
ORDER BY tours.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `group by` and `count()` doesn't belong in a `where` clause.

I would suggest doing this with a subquery, though:

```
SELECT tours.id
FROM tours LEFT JOIN
     (select registrants.tour_att, count(*) as numr
      from registrants
      group by registrants.tour_att
     ) as r
     ON tours.id = r.tour_att
WHERE numr < tours.capacity OR numr IS NULL
ORDER BY tours.id;
```

This code is summarizing the `registrants` by tour, to get the numer of registrants on each tour.  *Then* it is joining back to the `tours` table and applying the condition that you want.

Comment: Thanks so much! Would you mind adding some comments in your code explaining what it's doing? I'm still learning SQL and this will help me to learn.

Comment: This works well, except when I have no registrants for a specified `tours.id`. When that happens, it doesn't return that `id` as an option. If all the `registrants.tour_att` fields are blank, I get no results back. I tried using a `Left Join`, but that didn't work. Any advice?